# Getting char from reference char of another String in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to get **nTh** char from **target1** or **target2** but using a reference char of **abc** String.
But **result2** is not working as expected...

```
let abc = "abcde"
let target1 = "12345"
let target2 = ""
    
let m = abc.firstIndex(of: "c")!
    
let result1 = target1[m] //want "3"  //working
let result2 = target2[m] //want "" //not working
```

Comment:  isn't the same as "c"

Comment: @aheze how do I get  when I have **c** from **abc** string

Comment: You should use arrays instead of strings if you would like to share indices

Answer (score 1):

String subscripting is a pretty bad idea, but if you insist on using it, you have to use `distance` and `offset`, not an absolute `index`. Like this:

```
    let abc = "abcde"
    let target1 = "12345"
    let target2 = ""
    
    let d = abc.distance(from: abc.startIndex, to: abc.firstIndex(of: "c")!)
    
    let result1 = target1[target1.index(target1.startIndex, offsetBy:d)]
    let result2 = target2[target2.index(target2.startIndex, offsetBy:d)]
```